# Comic book series about dystopian child regime

Tags: story-identification, comics, childrens-novel, dystopia

My memories are somewhat vague on this one. I remember receiving 2 volumes of this series from my aunt when I was a child (somewhere around 10 - I'm now 21). The two books were set in a world that resembled a dystopia of some sort. I believe there are more entries to this series as there wasn't a definitive closure by the end of them. The visual style of the comic book resembled the animated show *Code Lyoko*... at least that's the way I remember it.

The villain of the story was a little child-emperor/dictator (again, so I think). Children were killed and it featured a lot of blood and gore despite its child-like aesthetic (I think). In it there was also a cat-man figure (probably the main protagonist) and a little girl that was always in her panties. She was barely dressed, if not fully naked above her waist for most of the story. Both of them traveled together? And I think by the end of one of the two volumes, the cat-man figure ended up taking part in a fist tournament where he was forced to fight against some enemies.

It was as dystopian as one could imagine, with the general colour scheme being quite muddy, brownish and dark. Also, I think the children looked Asian. And I also think that the cat-man figure used to fly a plane or something and was dressed in a light-brown, long
jacket.

It also featured people that were half-robots, different species,... The area around which the villain lived featured some snow I think. And some children were held in labs and experimented on. That's about all I can recall. Oh, and the books features were: hardback, large and big, but extremely thin - as comic books usually come. I also think all of the children had closely cropped hair.